# ModalViewController frame moving

Tags: ios, view, modalviewcontroller

I'm not sure if I can do this in this way, but let's have a try with smarter people then me.

I want to be able to move the frame of presented controller by dragging it. I'm expecting to see controller in which I've invoked the [self presentModalViewController:anotherVC animated:YES]; below the presented one. I'm seeing white background thou.

In order to achive  this functionality without presenting modal view controller I could add subview i.e.:

```
[self.view addSubview:anotherVC.view];
```

But is there a way to move modal presented view controller and be able to see view from which this modal controller is presented in?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display the parent view behind the modal view, then you can use this code:

Set your `anotherVC.view.frame` less than your parent view.

```
anotherVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:anotherVC animated:YES];
```

But the visible portion of the parent view will be dimmed for preventing the interaction.

> UIModalPresentationFormSheet
>
> ```
> The width and height of the presented view are smaller than those of the screen and the view is centered onscreen. If the device is in a
> ```
>
> landscape orientation and the keyboard is visible, the position of the
>   view is adjusted upward so the view remains visible. All uncovered
>   areas are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with them.

[Modal Presentation Styles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationStyle)

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work. I've tried to change origin.y and all I've got was white background. The way I've solved the issue is by making a screenshot of parent view controller and using it as background for my modal view controller (of course as UIIMageView).